# Import data from excel into DataGridview with specific condition

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

This is how i am import my `Excel` file:

```
stirng file = "c:\myFile.xlsx";
DataGridView dgvIM;

private void Import()
        {
            String name = "Items";
            String constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                            file +
                            ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;';";

            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
            OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [" + name + "$]", con);
            con.Open();

            OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
            System.Data.DataTable data = new System.Data.DataTable();
            sda.Fill(data);
            dgvIM.DataSource = data;
        }
```

What i want to do is import my Excel file but with specific condition, my second column contain several groups of strings ("First", "Second" etc..) and i want to add only the column with name "First" and not the whole list.

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a where condition on the sql command like this

```
string cmdText = "Select * From [" + name + "$] WHERE secondColumnName = 'First'";
using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr))
using(OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand(cmdText con))
{
     con.Open();
     OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
     System.Data.DataTable data = new System.Data.DataTable();
     sda.Fill(data);
     dgvIM.DataSource = data;
}
```

Note that in your connectionstring you specify HDR=YES, this means that the first non blank line of your excel sheet contains headers that are interpreted as column names. You should update your query setting the correct column name in the WHERE condition

**EDIT** In response at your comments below, if you want to retrieve every row where AGE is 12 the query becomes

```
string cmdText = "Select * From [" + name + "$] WHERE Age = 12";
```

Comment: If this is not the second column name but the third column value ? (the first row is the header)

Comment: I don't understand. Could you give an example of your data and what do you want to retrieve?

Comment: My first row is only the header name for example: name, id, age and that in the next rows the values for example John, Haze, 12 so i want all the values with 12

Comment: The first rows is ignored when you have HDR=YES, it is considered the columns name. So if you want to search for Age (third column) you where SELECT * FROM ... WHERE Age = 12 (I assume that the column Age contains numbers, so you don't need to use single quotes around your value

Comment: This is my line: string cmdText = "Select * From [" + name + "$] WHERE Protocol == 'TCP'"; (my third column is protocol and i want all the TCP protocols) and received error: 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Comment: This is how my file looks like: http://oi61.tinypic.com/2cygoev.jpg i want all the rows with specific values from Protocol column

Comment: Steve has given you a good answer for `Age`, and it should be easy to modify for `Protocol`. In your comment you use two equal signs like `==`. That wont work, use `WHERE Protocol = 'TCP'`